# Does the Amazon SQS Queue have a specified IP range or subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I need to know if the Amazon SQS Queue has a specified IP range or subnet that it lives in. The reason being is my firewall needs an exact range of IPs that it is allowed to connect to.

I found [AWS IP address ranges - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) in the AWS Docs. SQS Queues are not one of the services that show up on the json file and I am not sure which service it would be under.

What is the best range of IPs that I can use to add to my firewall?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-sending-messages-from-vpc.html)?

Comment: Where is your firewall? Is it within AWS, or is it an on-premises system? I agree, the range of IP addresses for Amazon SQS has not been published.

Comment: It is a on prem firewall

Answer (score 2):

> SQS Queues are not one of the services that show up on the json file

Indeed, as shown by parsing the json file:

```
% curl -s https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json | jq -r '.prefixes[] | .service' | sort -u
AMAZON
AMAZON_APPFLOW
AMAZON_CONNECT
API_GATEWAY
CHIME_MEETINGS
CHIME_VOICECONNECTOR
CLOUD9
CLOUDFRONT
CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_FACING
CODEBUILD
DYNAMODB
EBS
EC2
EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT
GLOBALACCELERATOR
KINESIS_VIDEO_STREAMS
ROUTE53
ROUTE53_HEALTHCHECKS
ROUTE53_HEALTHCHECKS_PUBLISHING
ROUTE53_RESOLVER
S3
WORKSPACES_GATEWAYS
```

So the best we can do is to figure out which service SQS is classified under. Look up some SQS IPs and correlate them back to the ranges file:

```
% nslookup sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com 1.1.1.1
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com canonical name = us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com.
Name:   us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com
Address: 44.242.184.144
```

**This IP corresponds to a CIDR mask marked as `AMAZON` back in the `ip-ranges.json` file**:

```
{
  "ip_prefix": "44.242.184.128/25",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "service": "AMAZON",
  "network_border_group": "us-west-2"
}
```

It's not very specific, corresponding to nearly 4600 ipv4 ranges:

```
% curl -s https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json | jq -r '.prefixes[] | select( .service == "AMAZON" ) | .ip_prefix' | wc -l
4592
```

This is the best I can do with the docs they've given us.